# Accent insensitive in filter backend to datatable in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, linq, filter, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I made a method on the back-end side to handle the filter of my datatable.

On the other hand, this one does not manage the accents of the French language, so if I have "école" and I write "ecole" it cannot find it.

I found this method on another question on stackoverflow

```
public static String RemoveDiacritics(this String s)
{
    String normalizedString = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
    {
        Char c = normalizedString[i];

        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

and it works, but only for part of my problem. It works on the letter or the word that is written in the search, but I am not able to apply it in my linq query, so with the `.RemoveDiacritics()` method my "école" becomes "ecole", but I don't am not able to apply it in the column of my table and it always looks for "école".

Here the code for the search:

```
if (search != null)
{
    int n;
    search = search.Trim();

    var isNumeric = int.TryParse(search, out n);

    if (isNumeric)
    {
        IdFilter = n;
        query = query.Where(x => x.UsagerId == IdFilter || x.Niveau == IdFilter);
    }
    else if (search != "")
    {
        // this line work
        textFilter = search.ToLower().RemoveDiacritics();
        // This is the full line, but absolutely takes the accents out to get the right information out
        // query = query.Where(x => x.Nom.ToLower().Contains(textFilter) || x.Prenom.ToLower().Contains(textFilter) || x.Username.ToLower().Contains(textFilter) || x.Email.ToLower().Contains(textFilter) || x.EtabNom.ToLower().Contains(textFilter) || x.ActifStatut.ToLower().Contains(textFilter));
    
        // This is the line that will replace the line above, which I try and it doesn't work ( this part: x.Prenom.ToLower().RemoveDiacritics())
        query = query.Where(x => x.Prenom.ToLower().RemoveDiacritics().Contains(textFilter)); 
    }
}
```

This is the basic query:

```
IQueryable<ListeUsagers> query = (from u in db.USAGERs
                             join e in db.ETABLISSEMENTs on u.USAGER_INST equals e.ETAB_CODE
                             where u.USAGER_INST == instId && u.USAGER_NIVEAU > 3 && u.USAGER_NIVEAU < 5 //&& u.USAGER_ACTIF == 1
                             select new ListeUsagers()
                             {
                                 UsagerId = u.USAGER_id,
                                 Nom = u.USAGER_NOM,
                                 Prenom = u.USAGER_PRENOM,
                                 EtabCode = e.ETAB_CODE,
                                 EtabNom = e.ETAB_NOM_COURT,
                                 EtabType = e.ETAB_TYPE,
                                 Niveau = u.USAGER_NIVEAU,
                                 Username = u.USAGER_USERNAME,
                                 UserPassword = u.USAGER_MP,
                                 DateCreation = u.USAGER_DATE_INSC,
                                 Sexe = u.USAGER_SEXE,
                                 Lang = u.USAGER_LANGUE,
                                 Telephone = u.USAGER_TELEPHONE,
                                 Email = u.USAGER_EMAIL,
                                 FonctionTravail = u.USAGER_FONCTION,
                                 LieuTravail = u.USAGER_LIEUTRAVAIL,
                                 Note = u.USAGER_NOTE,
                                 Actif = u.USAGER_ACTIF,
                                 ActifStatut = u.USAGER_ACTIF == 0 ? "Inactif" : "Actif"
                             });
```

This is the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String RemoveDiacritics(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

There's built-in functionality to do this in entityframework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity if you're using EF 5+

You'll want an accent insensitive collation  ("AI", not "AS" in the examples on that page.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it's for .net core and I can't find the equivalent for mvc 5, so I'm in the same situation